# A problem involving ideals and prime ideals.

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

Please help me with a solution to this problem.

Let $R$ be a commutative ring. Let $A_1, A_2$ be two ideals of $R$, and $P_1, P_2$ two prime ideals of $R$.

Assume that $A_1 \cap A_2 \subseteq  P_1 \cap P_2$. Show that there exist $i, j \in \{1,2\}$ such that $A_i \subseteq P_j$.

Comment: @Roland, i did some editing in your question so it would be clearer - is that what you wanted to ask?

Comment: Have redrawn my hint- question formulation has changed.

Comment: Ty for editing. This is correct and should be A_i ⊆ P_j. Not ≤.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/776101/ideals-and-prime-ideals-in-a-commutative-ring